# TableView action per item

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a tableView like this:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
            
            @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
            
            let names = ["TEXT1", "TEXT2", "TEXT3"]
            
            
        
            override func viewDidLoad()
            {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
                
                tableView.delegate = self
                tableView.dataSource = self
                 
            }
        }
    
    
    extension ViewControllerMeer: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let name = names[indexPath.row]
        print("You clicked on \(name)")
    }
        
}
 
 extension ViewControllerMeer: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
     
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
 }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
        
        let n = names[indexPath.item]
        switch n {
        case "TEXT1":
            print("s1")
        case "TEXT2":
            print("s2")
        case "TEXT3":
            print("s3")
        default:
            break
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    

}
```

It reads the items from the 'let names', So far so good :) I now want to add some actions because now every item will print 'You tapped me'. I figured something out like

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
      print("cell1")
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
      print("cell2")
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
      print("cell3")
    }
  }
```

The only problem is that it generates an error 'Method does not override any method from its superclass'. So I guess this won't work. What would be a good method to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `override` in front of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

And you can either to a big if statement or switch statement to do something with the names or you can do something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let name = names[indexPath.row]
    print("You clicked on \(name)")
    
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
             //do something
             self.shareApp()
        case 1:
             //do something else
             self.writeReview()
        default:
            break
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated my original code. I'm trying to add a switch but it doesn't effect the outcome. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: @DeDeSchurk I guess it depends on what you're trying to do.  Whats the end goal?  I added a simple switch statement above for indexPath.row

Comment: Calling a function @lavta3 (for example share this app on row0, write app review on row1 etc etc)

Comment: @DeDeSchurk Updated answer.  You should be able to call whatever functions you have from inside that switch statement

Comment: and make sure you only have one `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) `

Comment: Got it! Thanks, got it all worked out now! Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your codes to show you basically if you really want to override tableview functions

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let names = ["TEXT1", "TEXT2", "TEXT3"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
      }
  }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped me!")
  }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
  }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let name = names[indexPath.row]
    print("You clicked on \(name)")
  }
 }
```